# No Hibernate Session bound to thread grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, quartz-scheduler

Actually we've lot of quartz jobs in our application. For some time all of the jobs work fine. After some time all jobs are throwing the following exception.

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here]
at grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzDisplayJob.execute(QuartzDisplayJob.groovy:37)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
at grails.plugins.quartz.QuartzDisplayJob.execute(QuartzDisplayJob.groovy:29)
... 2 more
```